# Centering two elements horizontally?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, alignment

I have this problem where I want to line up two elements (a `<p>` and a `<button>`) but I can't seem to find a way of lining them up; I have tried using padding, margin, flex and even grid design, but nothing seems to work.

Here is an image showcasing the problem:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAeNQ.png)

And here is a code snippet of my latest attempt:

```css
.line p {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: lightgray solid 1px;
}

.activeLine {
  color: #38B938;
  background-color: white;
}

.buttonsActive {
  background-color: inherit;
  border: 1.5px solid #38B938;
  color: #38B938;
  padding: 8px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.inactiveLine {
  background-color: white;
}

.inactiveLine {
            background-color: white;
        }

        .buttonsA {
            background-color: inherit;
            color: black;
            padding: 8px 15px;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 16px;
            margin: 4px 2px;
            cursor: pointer;
            font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
            border-radius: 50%;
            float: right;
            margin-right: 10px;

        }

        .buttonsA:hover {
            color: #38B938;
            transition: linear 0.5s;
        }

        .buttonsA:first-child {
            margin-left: 10px;
            float:left;
            border: 1.5px solid black;
        }

        .buttonsA:first-child:hover {
            color: #38B938;
            border: 1.5px solid #38B938;
            transition: linear 0.5s;
        }

        .buttonsActive:first-child {
            margin-left: 10px;
            float:left;
        }
```

```html
<div class="voiceGrid">
  <div class="titleVoiceBanner">
    <h2 class="textVoiceTitle">Problem for  </h2>
    <h3 class="textVoiceSubtlt">Stack Overflow</h3>
  </div>

 
  <div>
    <audio id="player1">
       <source type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
    <div class="line inactiveLine" id="line1">
      <p>
        <button id="buttonPlay" class="buttonsA">▶</i></button>  
        
        Loc 1
        
      </p>

    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually quite easy with [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). Make the p tag a flex element and then use the [`align-items: center;`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_align-items.asp) to make them appear on the same line.

```css
.line p {
  display: flex; /* Change from inline-block to flex */
  align-items: center; /* Added to make them appear on the same line */
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: lightgray solid 1px;
}

.activeLine {
  color: #38B938;
  background-color: white;
}

.buttonsActive {
  background-color: inherit;
  border: 1.5px solid #38B938;
  color: #38B938;
  padding: 8px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.inactiveLine {
  background-color: white;
}

.inactiveLine {
            background-color: white;
        }

        .buttonsA {
            background-color: inherit;
            color: black;
            padding: 8px 15px;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 16px;
            margin: 4px 2px;
            cursor: pointer;
            font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
            border-radius: 50%;
            float: right;
            margin-right: 10px;

        }

        .buttonsA:hover {
            color: #38B938;
            transition: linear 0.5s;
        }

        .buttonsA:first-child {
            margin-left: 10px;
            float:left;
            border: 1.5px solid black;
        }

        .buttonsA:first-child:hover {
            color: #38B938;
            border: 1.5px solid #38B938;
            transition: linear 0.5s;
        }

        .buttonsActive:first-child {
            margin-left: 10px;
            float:left;
        }
```

```html
<div class="voiceGrid">
  <div class="titleVoiceBanner">
    <h2 class="textVoiceTitle">Problem for  </h2>
    <h3 class="textVoiceSubtlt">Stack Overflow</h3>
  </div>

 
  <div>
    <audio id="player1">
       <source type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
    <div class="line inactiveLine" id="line1">
      <p>
        <button id="buttonPlay" class="buttonsA">▶</i></button>  
        
        Loc 1
        
      </p>

    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I had tried flex, but not in that way.